# How to find all classes in a package?

Tags: java, android

[Find all classes in a package in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446036/find-all-classes-in-a-package-in-android)

The solutions above use DexFile which has been deprecated since API 26. I'm wondering if there is a solution that isn't deprecated.

Comment: you may want to visit this link https://dzone.com/articles/get-all-classes-within-package