# List all classes in a package on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm attempting to retrieve a list of classes in a given package name on Android. I have a working method which looks like this:

```kotlin
fun getClasses(context: Context, packageName: String): List<Class<*>> {
    val dexFile = DexFile(context.applicationInfo.sourceDir)
    return dexFile.entries().asSequence()
        .filter { it.startsWith(packageName) }
        .map { context.classLoader.loadClass(it) }.toList()
}
```

The issue with this implementation is that is uses the deprecated [DexFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile) class. I've attempted to use several of the implementations found in the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446036/find-all-classes-in-a-package-in-android) however I was unable to get any of them to return any classes.

Is it possible to retrieve a list of classes in a given package on Android without using the `DexFile` class?