# What does dollar sign mean in generated variable names during debugging Java in InteliJ IDEA ? Is it a closure?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, reactive-programming, sodium

What does dollar sign mean in variable names during debugging Java in InteliJ ? Is it a closure ? Please see the image and code snippet below.

Here is part of the Stream class:

```
public final Listener listen(final Handler<A> action) {
    return listen_(Node.NULL, new TransactionHandler<A>() {
        public void run(Transaction trans2, A a) {
            action.run(a);
        }
    });
}
```

I suspect that the `$1` in `Stream$1@915` refers to the closure created in the method above. I am not sure though. Can someone confirm this ? Or if that is not the case, explain what the dollar sign means in this generated name ?

The [code](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium/blob/master/java/sodium/src/sodium/Stream.java) is taken from the Sodium Functional Reactive library which I am trying understand how it works.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java compiled classes contain dollar signs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388840/java-compiled-classes-contain-dollar-signs), also maybe [What is the meaning of $ in a variable name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name).

Comment: Thanks ! I searched for answers on SOF but found nothing, perhapsI was searching with the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a reference to the anonymous inner class thats generated by this closure like construct.  In general, inner classes are compiled and the class file name will be `yourClassName$yourInnerClassName`.  In the case of an anonymous inner class declaration, since you don't name it explicitly, it will appear as a generated name using numbers.  Perhaps this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077411/core-java/inner-classes.html) will help?