# com.google.common.collect.Iterables and the instance type

Tags: java, guava

I have this groovy script that is executed on nexus:

```
def retentionDays = 30;
def retentionCount = 10;
def repositoryName = 'maven-releases';
def whitelist = ["org.javaee7.sample/javaee7-simple-sample", "org.javaee7.next/javaee7-another-sample"].toArray();

log.info(":::Cleanup script started!");

MaintenanceService service = container.lookup("org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maintenance.MaintenanceService");
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repositoryName);
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet.class).txSupplier().get();
def components = null;
try {
    tx.begin();
    components = tx.browseComponents(tx.findBucket(repo));
}catch(Exception e){
    log.info("Error: "+e);
}finally{
    if(tx!=null)
        tx.close();
}

log.info(" - - A - - Type of 'components.getClass().getName()' is: " +  components.getClass().getName());
log.info(" - - B - - Type of 'components' is: " +  components);
log.info(" - - C - - Type of 'components.getClass()' is: " +  components.getClass());
log.info(" - - D - - Type of 'components[0].getClass()' is: " +  components[0].getClass());


log.info(" - - components instanceof com.google.common.collect.Iterables = " + (components instanceof com.google.common.collect.Iterables));
```

When that is run I get:

```
     -  - - A - - Type of 'components.getClass().getName()' is: com.google.common.collect.Iterables$4
     -  - - B - - Type of 'components' is: []
     -  - - C - - Type of 'components.getClass()' is: class com.google.common.collect.Iterables$4
     -  - - components instanceof com.google.common.collect.Iterables = false
     -  - - D - - Type of 'components[0].getClass()' is: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
```

Why is `components` not an instance of `com.google.common.collect.Iterables` ?

I would expect that I could do:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables
Iterables components = null;
try {
    tx.begin();
    components = tx.browseComponents(tx.findBucket(repo));
}catch(Exception e){
    log.info("Error: "+e);
}finally{
    if(tx!=null)
        tx.close();
}
```

But that gives the error:

```
Error: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'com.google.common.collect.Iterables$4' to class 'com.google.common.collect.Iterables'
```

How do I strongly type the variable:

```
   def components = null;
```

?

When I look at the java docs:
https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html

its does not look like `com.google.common.collect.Iterables` is a sub class of `java.lang.Iterable`

Based on below answer I can do:

```
Iterable<Component> components = null;
```

But how do I find that `com.google.common.collect.Iterables$4` without "guessing"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Iterables`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) is a utility class (it contains only static method and cannot be instantiated).

I guess that your `com.google.common.collect.Iterables$4` is just some anonymous class implementing [`java.lang.Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

To sum up, defining `components` as `Iterable` should work for you.

---

*EDIT*: To answer your follow-up questions:

1) You wrote that it does not look like [`Iterables`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) implements [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), and you're right - it doesn't. In order to understand what `com.google.common.collect.Iterables$4` means you need to understand the [compilation naming rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388863/2032415) of [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

In short, `com.google.common.collect.Iterables$4` means "4th anonymous class nested in `com.google.common.collect.Iterables` class".

2) As to how you find out the type without guessing - you simply track the API and what it returns:

- [`Repository.facet`](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/Repository.java#L112) returns a `Facet` of given type (here: `StorageFacet`)
- [`StorageFacet.txSupplier`](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/StorageFacet.java#L44) returns `Supplier<StorageTx>`
- [`StorageTx.browseComponents`](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/StorageTx.java#L154) returns `Iterable<Component>`

Note that it's all interfaces above, so we still don't see from this how the returned `Iterable<Component>` is implemented.

To find out about this, we need to see into the implementation: [`StorageTxImpl`](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/StorageTxImpl.java#L318). This, however, delegates the call further and I don't feel like tracing it any further (you can do it on your own if you wish; it'd much be easier to do if one opened this project in an IDE, though).

However, I know that what happens there is that a call to one of the methods in Guava's `Iterables` utility class is made, which in turn returns `Iterable<T>` implemented by means of an anonymous class, and that's all.