# com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList throws away my elements

Tags: java, guava

I have this code:

```
int size = Iterables.size(components);
log.info("Number of components found (before convert): " +  size);

List<Component> listOfComponents = Lists.newArrayList(components);
size = listOfComponents.size();
log.info("Number of components found (after convert): " +  size);

for (Component component : listOfComponents) {
  log.info("component :  " + component);
}
```

Where `Component` is: `org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Component`

When I run it it prints:

```
Number of components found (before convert): 2
Number of components found (after convert): 0
```

So after I convert my iterable to a list the elements are no longer there. Also I never get into the following loop.

why does the elements not get copied to the list, thats what the docs say:

> Creates a mutable ArrayList instance containing the given elements; a
>   very thin shortcut for creating an empty list then calling
>   Iterables.addAll.

Comment: What is the type of `components`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You need to understand that an `Iterable` returned by Guava's [`Iterables`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) is a once-only iterable.</del> *It turns out your `Iterable` is a once-only iterable.*<sup>1</sup> After you iterate it once, it doesn't throw upon subsequent iteration but instead is empty.

Hence, your calling [`Iterables.size`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#size-java.lang.Iterable-) on it effectively empties the `Iterable`, and that's why the resulting `ArrayList` is empty.

Instead, you should dump your `Iterable` to an `ArrayList` as soon as possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sentence deleted because it turns out that Guava adheres to the de-facto standard of `Iterable`s being [iterable multiple times](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#a-method-to-view-an-iterator-as-an-iterable).

Comment: awesome answer !

Comment: I agree that `components` is a once-only iterable, but Guava does not provide any once-only iterables. The once-only iterable is coming from somewhere else. (At most, Guava might be wrapping an existing once-only iterable, resulting in another once-only iterable.)

Comment: Yeah, as @ChrisPovirk says, once-only iterables are something that Guava _explicitly_ avoids providing, despite numerous requests for, say, a method that creates an `Iterable` view of an `Iterator` (which would be once-only).

Comment: @ChrisPovirk @ColinD: I apologize for posting this false claim about `Iterables`. I should have checked this before posting. You might wonder how I knew it's an `Iterable` from Guava - I knew it from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641345/2032415). So indeed, as @ChrisPovirk suggested, it must have been the case that Guava wrapped an existing once-only `Iterable`. Anyway, I take the downvote as well-deserved ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Iterables.size(components)`  it uses the `Iterable` you pass and iterates through the collection (calling `hasNext` and `next` on the `Iterator` from the passed `Iterable`) to find out the size.

So, when you make the second call to `newArrayList`, the `Itertor` is empty now (calling `hasNext` will return false).

You need to create a new Iterable and pass to `newArrayList`