# Kotlin: Referencing anonymous object from itself / inside (via this)

Tags: android, kotlin, this, anonymous-class

**TL;DR** 
These `object : someClass{ }` anonymous objects can't access itself via `this` (which results the **outer object**). **How can I access it?**

**Longer explanation:**

For my Fragment I need a PreDrawListener. I call this in onCreateView. When executing, I wanted to remove the listener afterwards. So the Java way of doing would suggest something like this

```
  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,    

  val treeObserver = layout.viewTreeObserver

  treeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
     override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
        layout.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
        ...
     }
  }
```

The problem is, when taking a look at the `removeOnPreDrawListener(this)` the `this` object is not the listener but `myFragment$onCreateView$1@f019bf0`

Alternatively I could access `this@MyFragment` which returns the reference to the Fragment directly.

Still, none of these options seems to be my `PreDrawListener`. **How can I access it from inside (if at all)?**

Comment: This definitely works in Kotlin, I've just tried it. Also, [here's](https://github.com/android/android-ktx/blob/89ee2e1cde1e1b0226ed944b9abd55cee0f9b9d4/src/main/java/androidx/core/view/View.kt#L75) this exact thing implemented in the android-ktx library, which also works. Maybe there's a problem with your setup, or you're somehow in the wrong scope? Could you post a minimal verifiable example?

Comment: `myFragment$onCreateView$1@f019bf0` is the listener's `toString()` inherited implementation. You should be able to override it (in addition to `onPreDraw`) and see it change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly don't see your problem.

`this` inside an anonymous refers to the class itself, but they never have names. You can't create an anonymous class with a name. To demo this, I wrote some sample code:

```
class TheClass{
    fun run(){
        val anon = object: Runnable {
            override fun run() {}
        }
        println(anon::class.java.simpleName)
        println(anon::class.java.name)
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
run$anon$1
com.package.TheClass$run$anon$1
```

Now, this is nice and all, but it still doesn't look like yours. But you see it matches the containing class, method, variable, and finally the dollar sign denoting that it's an anonymous inner class. That applies to the second, which is the full one. The first just prints the short name, which is the method, var name, and again the dollar sign that shows it's anonymous function.

If you're interested in why the dollar sign with a number appears, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388863/6296561). T

Let's expand that and ditch the variable. Obviously, this is horrible code (and far from memory-efficient, but it's a demo so it doesn't matter):

```
class TheClass {
    fun run(){
        println(object: Runnable {
            override fun run() { }
        })
    }
}
```

This prints, and matching your pattern:

```
com.package.TheClass$run$anon$1
```

You've seen the pattern; now you can start "decoding" the hash you got:

```
myFragment // inside myFragment
$onCreateView // Inside a function
$1 // There is an anonymous class with a specific identifier
@f019bf0 // This is standard everywhere; just look up Object.toString()
```

What I just tried to prove is: `this` does refer to the anonymous function you create. Anonymous functions are, well, anonymous. They don't have names. They use `$number` as identifiers. So if you have this code:

```
treeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
    override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
       layout.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
       ...
    }
 }
```

`this` will refer to the listener, even though printing the class may print stuff that looks confusing. If there's something that's broken, it's not because of `this` not referring to the listener (because it does)

Also, your code compiles fine. There's no type mismatch in there either. If it referred to a different object, it wouldn't work if you passed `this` to a method that requires a `OnPreDrawListener`.

---

You would get a different result with the same code in Java. This is because Kotlin compiles anonymous functions as `Class$function$number`, where as Java compiles it to `Class$number`. If it's in a nested class, it will appear as `Outer$Inner$function$number` in Kotlin, and `Outer$Inner$number` in Java.

It's a difference in the compiler that results in different names; Java excludes the function, where as Kotlin includes it. It's in the `.class` filename, so if you build your project and look at the file names in a file explorer for whatever OS you have (***Do not look in IntelliJ***. It will decompile the files for you. And remember, you're just looking for the name, which IntelliJ messes up by merging the .class files into a single one to match the original source)

---

<sub>Just as final meta, I do print the class instead of printing the object. Interfaces do not have an overridden toString method, which means it defaults to the one on Object, which returns `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());` (original code can be found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java)). `println(this)` is the same as `println(this.toString())`, which calls the toString method in Object, which prints the class name. `println(this)` is the same as printing the object or printing the class</sub>

Comment: Wow, goog explaination. So I simply misinterpreted the naming. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This doesn't explain how to refer to the anonymous object when there is a naming conflict between the object and the containing class, like a member and a local variable with the same name. For that you need something like this@???, but it's not clear what to use.

Comment: @Zoe Cool explanation. I have a similar issue that I've posted here (https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-reference-an-anonymous-inner-class-from-the-outer-class/18784). Could you take a look and provide insight into it?