# How to get inner class Reflection

Tags: java, kotlin

I had a class like

```
package example.com
class TContract : Contract {
    interface Commands : CommandData {
        class TIssue(val reference: State) : Commands
    }
}
```

How to get the class reflection of TIssue. I tried `Class.forName("example.com.TContract.Commands.TIssue")`, but it's not work!

Comment: `Class.forName("example.com.TContract\$Commands\$TIssue")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner classes will be compiled and the class file will be `ClassName$InnerClassName`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388863/1048340

You need to escape the dollar sign character in Kotlin. The following will work:

`Class.forName("example.com.TContract\$Commands\$TIssue")`

Comment: Regarding your edit to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27813407/revisions - my mod flag to get it undeleted was declined with the rather churlish reason of "Then they can use a flag themselves."