# Compilation error when try to access inner static enum in a .jar file

Tags: java, enums, jar

I'm trying to access a inner static enum Status in a .jar file but I'm getting a compilation error and I don't know why.

Message.java:

```
package com.sockets.protocol;

public class Message {

    public static enum Status {
        OK, ERROR, PARAMERROR, REQUEST;
    }

    private String operation;

    public Message(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    // more code here but irrelevant for this problem
}
```

Compiling and creating .jar file:

```
javac -d . com/sockets/protocol/Message.java
jar -cvf Message.jar com/sockets/procotol/Message.class
```

Server.java

```
package com.sockets.server;

import com.sockets.protocol.Message;

public class Server implements Serializable {

    private int port;
    private Message message;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        this.message = new Message("op-test")
        System.out.println("test status: " + Message.Status.OK);
        System.out.println("test operation: " + message.getOperation());
    }
}
```

When I comment out the first System.out.println the program runs fine. So how can I fix this?

Error message:

```
[xxx@xxxxxxx src]$ javac -cp .:../library/Message.jar -d . com/sockets/server/Main.java
./com/sockets/server/Server.java:31: error: cannot access Status
        System.out.println("teste message: " + Message.Status.OK);
                                                      ^
  class file for com.sockets.protocol.Message$Status not found
1 error
```

Comment: Well, when you write `jar -cvf Message.jar com/sockets/procotol/Message.class` you surely have checked that your code only creates that one class file, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java compiled classes contain dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388840/java-compiled-classes-contain-dollar-signs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly put all classes in the jar.

```
jar -cvf Message.jar Message.class Message\$Status.class
```

You'll note that the 'v' option tells you what is going into the jar, and in your case, the Status enum was not listed.

The name of the enum is Message$Status, but the dollar sign needs to be escaped as `\$` if this is Linux or similar.